# Is using @if(Auth::user()) the same as @auth in my blade view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I realized I am using 2 ways to prevent people who are not logged from seeing stuff that are meant for members only. The first one is using `@if(Auth::user())` and the second one is using `@auth`. For example:

```
@auth
    <button class="submit-btn like liked" id='{{ $image->id }}'>
@endauth
```

And

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <button class="submit-btn like liked" id='{{ $image->id }}'>
@endif
```

Is there any difference between those 2 examples or should I just stick to one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [version 5.4.29](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-v5-4-29) they are basically the same. The shorter `@auth` and `@endauth` are only a shorter/hidden way for the if-else construction. For your own comfort, it is a good idea to stick to one of them.

The real moment it shines is when you are using guards, so you don't have to do something like this (assuming you have a usertype 'administrator'):

```
@if(Auth::user()->type === 'administrator')
```

Instead, the following suffices:

```
@auth('administrator')
```

Comment: For the second one, you need to define a auth `guard`...

Answer (score 1):

More correctly to use:

`Auth::check()` `Auth::guest()` in your code because they return `bool`.

`auth()->check()` `auth()->guest()` (same with helper).

And `@auth` `@guest` in Blade template files.